# How to pair vectors with different lengths?

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors with different lengths:

```
 a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
 b=[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Is there a way to match and combine them like this random combination?

```
        A    B
        1    2
        2    3
        3    5
        4    3
        5    2
        6    1
        7    3
        8    5
        9    2 
        10   1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "match them and combine them"?  What kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: you will have to be more specific regarding the outcome you are seeking.

Comment: Just take a random subsample of size `numel(a)` from `b`. For example `[a; b(randperm(numel(b),numel(a)))]`.

Comment: My bad ! actually I want to pair them and that was my question . Sorry you guys !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but if you want to sample 10 values (length of `a`) out of the vector `b`, you can use the [randsample](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/randsample.html) function with replacement if you have the Statistics toolbox:

```
[a; b(randsample(numel(b),numel(a),true))]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     5     5     3     5     1     3     5     4     5
```

If you don't have the statistics toolbox, you can generate the indices yourself easily:

```
[a; b(randi(numel(b),size(a)))]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     4     1     2     1     1     4     4     2     5     1
```

Comment: Instead of `randsample` you can use `randi(numel(a), size(a))` if you don't have the Statistics Toolbox installed

Comment: Thanks @EitanT, I forgot about `randi` (but with `numel(b)` instead of `numel(a)`). Modified the answer!

Comment: Ok I have a question . What If I don't want a random sample and want it in a specified way ,like I defined it ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to pair every element in vector A with an element from vector B.

One way of doing that is as follows:

```
%replicate B so that it is at least as big as A
c = repmat(b, 1, ceil(length(a)./length(b)));

% randomly shuffle the resulting vector
c = c(randperm(length(c)));

% crop it to the same length as A
c = c(1:length(a));
```

Comment: Yes I actually wanted to pair them. Sorry couldn't get hold of the right word

Comment: Note: Marc's answer is better than this.

Comment: Thank you ! I will consider it !